# jsch channel is not opened

Tags: java, exception, sftp, jsch

i'm trying to open an exec and an sftp channel simultaneously but when i open the sftp channel gives me an error, the code (simplified) is this:

```
JSch connection = new JSch();
Session session = connection.getSession(user, ip, port);
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect(15000);
ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
//exec commands whit channel
Channel ch;
ch = ssh.session.openChannel("sftp");
ch.connect();//-------ERROR!
ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp)ch;
```

the error is: "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: channel is not opened."

Answer (score 2):

Try to increase the timeout:

```
  ch.connect(60 * 1000); // A minute wait for connection.
```